# Place and retrieve images Java 3d

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I have no working experience of Java3d what so ever so I needed a quick information
where should I place images that I want to use in my project like the background of the panel 
like we have Drawable folder in android.

and also I have seen that the background need the image as ImageComponent2d how to convert that retrieved image to that format

searched for it all around but no good tutorial was available 
Any help is appreciated thanks in advace

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  Where to put/how to locate resources is entirely separate to converting an image to a specific component or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images on the run-time class path of the application (is the quick answer).